# Angular 4, Unexpected token error during ng build --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-2

I am working on an Angular 4 application that utilizes angular-cli and webpack2.

I can successfully build the project with `ng build`

However, when I run `ng build --prod` the following error is thrown:

> ERROR in main.50d83f3f70f7e607ec7a.bundle.js from UglifyJs Unexpected
>   token: name (FilterPipe) [main.50d83f3f70f7e607ec7a.bundle.js:7,6]

I don't understand what is wrong.

Here is my **filter.pipe.ts** file:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ 
    name: 'filter'
})

export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], field : string, value : string): any[] { 
        if (!items) return [];  
        return items.filter(it => it[field] == value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check that your target is not es6, which has known problems with uglify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Uglify doesnt support es6 syntax yet.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1663

Modify tsconfig.json to check fr sure that  "target": "es5", is there Example :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I've changed my tsconfig.json to have a "target": "es5" and I'm still getting this error. Is there any additional steps that I need to take to make sure this works?

Comment: @JustinGrahn I am facing a similar issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @kds23 oh boy, I did but there were multiple issues going on at once so let me try walk back. I think the first issue I had was resolved by forcing a different version of Uglify. Search around, but there is an Angular or Typescript thread detailing why this is necessary. Secondly the JIT compiler was allowing my component html to reference private variables, which for whatever reason, is not actually allowed when compiling with the AOT compiler that the —prod flag uses, so I had to convert every private variable that was being referenced by my HTML. I think the  Uglify version is your best bet